# $(":animated").length - Always return 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I execute the following command with the developer tools of firefox/chrome on a site with an animation it always return 0.

```
$(":animated").length
```

I want to find out how many animations are on the entire site.

Did I forgot anything?

I have have no code except this line. I only insert it in a chrome/firefox console.

Comment: why you checking the `:animated` ? for what purpose?

Comment: I want to find out how many animations are on the entire site.

Comment: replace `:` with `.`

Comment: What is `$(":animated")`?

Comment: are you sure there are animations going on when this code is executed?

Comment: You forgot to include all of the other code. Please include a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: yes, that `selector` are give correct output if the animation are running

Comment: @connexo http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/

Comment: On this site (https://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) is an animation. And the command returns 0.

Comment: :animated is a pseudo-class, not a standard CSS one though, but one generated by jQuery

Comment: give more details so we can help you, why you want to check the `:animated` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause you must select first the container.

It works with (Chrome)

```
$("body :animated").length
```

I've try on https://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/

[image: Chrome example]

Comment: Tried this in chrome console but returning 0.

Comment: I confirm... Typing `$("body :animated").length` in the console on the [demo page](https://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) is working... It returns 1. For me, it works on Chrome, but not on FireFox.

Comment: It fails in all the other browsers I have... (FF, Safari 5.1.7 for windows, Opera and Explorer 11) It only works in Chrome.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Yes i've tried too. But it works with Chrome :p
Can't find why

Comment: Don't know either... Chrome is the best ;)

Comment: It's working on the demo page because those animations are done by JQuery and running continously.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Open debugger in chrome.
2. Click the sources tab.
3. on the left side click the Snippets Tab
4. right click the empty white space and choose new
5. name it "script.js"
6. on the right under the script.js tab enter:
   `console.log($(document).find(':animated').length);`
7. Hit Ctrl+S to save
8. now right click the script.js file on the left and choose run

The console will output the number of animated elements on the document.
[image]